# Difference between importing airflow.DAG and airflow.models.DAG

Tags: python, airflow

Is there any difference between `from airflow import DAG` ([used in the tutorial in the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html)) and `from airflow.models import DAG` ([used in the example DAGs](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/6a66ece8cae8c8d209efefcde2639dca8919e975/airflow/example_dags/example_python_operator.py#L26))?

I'm new to Airflow and unsure if they should be used differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any difference?

**No**

---

Looking at the source code, following should behave identical

- `from airflow.models.dag import DAG`: this is the full-qualified import for the [`dag.py` module](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py)
- `from airflow.models import DAG`: this works the same as because `DAG` has been [imported in `__init__.py` of `models` package](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/__init__.py#L23)
- `from airflow import DAG`: this also works because `DAG` is [made available in `__init__.py` of `airflow`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/__init__.py#L38)